# Phonegap 2.1.0 Cordova/CDVViewController.h file not found

Tags: ios, cordova

I have installed Xcode 4.5 (no previous phonegap version installed). I have downloaded,extracted and created project by Phonegap tutorial : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS

After the terminal command : **./create myproject ~/Desktop/myproject com.test.myproject** I have successfly created structure.

Than i launch xcode and wanna Play this example project. Xcode build Fails and says:

**Lexical or proccessor issue 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found**

I tried to add this missing header in to classes folder, repaired the import syntax, but still same problem.

Does anybody solved this problem?/HOW?

Comment: I just experienced the exact same thing. I deleted the project and created a new one, problem solved. Not sure if it matters but I let xcode finish all its updates before I created the new project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After many attempts I decided to read **Readme.md** and solve the problem using **./update_cordova_subproject**!

Create project using:

```
./create ~/Desktop/project com.example.project project
```

Update cordova subproject reference:

```
./update_cordova_subproject ~/Desktop/project/project.xcodeproj
```

### Build successfull now!