# Unable to Create Archieve in xcode. cordova/CDVViewController.h missing

Tags: iphone, cordova, xcode4.3

I am using cordova in the Xcode, and Xcode version is 4.3.3.  The programming is running fine in the iphone, and when i try to create .ipa file through archieve, i could not able to, as it shouts at me saying "Cordova/CDVViewcontroller.h" file not found.

I check Build Settings.

```
Build Settings --> Search paths ---> Header Search Paths ---> Debug
                                                         |
                                                         |
                                                          ---> Release
```

In both [ Debug, Release ] , I double clicked and I fond the following check box checked.

```
"$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include"
"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include"
"$(BUILD_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
```

Am i missing any other options?.. Kindly advice.

Comment: [This answer might help you][1]

OR see [this question][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12940886/1441326
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12184767/1441326