# Unable to add Cordova.framework in XCode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode5

I have an old phone gap application (< = 1.9) and never ran phonegap application before in this machine and I am new in phonegap coding. I downloaded command line tool dmg for xcode from apple developer web site. I downloaded [phonegap 2.9.1](http://phonegap.com/install/). But I am not able to run existing phonegap application as `cordova.framework` is missing. After executing `cordova -v` in terminal, I get this version number `3.5.0-0.2.6`

How do I add Cordova.framework? I have attached the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Paulo's answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714600/cdvplugin-h-file-not-found-in-cordova-as-component-cleaver) I was able to solve my problem. Below is the solution.

The solution was to add the Cordovalib.xcodeproj to the target project, once done, click on your_project.xcodeproj - you will need to look in the Target Settings, under the Build Phases Tab, make sure that Cordovalib is added in Target Dependencies.

Once done it should allow the statement: #import to work.

Comment: even this link might help few people to solve this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921295/phonegap-2-1-0-cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found